# Laravel Default Auth - Adding Fields Breaks Login Ability

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm stuck with the default Laravel Auth. I generated it through `php artisan make:auth`.

My User table requires more fields than the default provides. Here is my migration for the table.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first', 20)->nullable();
            $table->string('last', 20)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('password', 20);
            $table->integer('userRoleId')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('userGroupId')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('companyId')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

I then edited the `User.php` Model and updated the `$fillable` fields.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'first', 'last', 'email', 'password', 'userRoleId', 'userGroupId', 'companyId',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

When I submit the form it posts properly to the database and is stored. I can see the row.

The problem is that now when I **logout** after creating a new user and return to **login** and fill out the form, it returns with errors stating that the email address I entered does not match any records even though there clearly is a row with the same data and same column name in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming you are using hashed password. Change `$table->string('password', 20);` to `$table->string('password', 60);`

Comment: That solved it! I didn't allow enough characters for the password hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@The Alpha's answer in the comments solved my problem.

My process was correct except for the fact that I didn't take into account that the password is hashed and not enough characters were made available to the hash in my database field.

`$table->string('password', 20);` needed to be changed to `$table->string('password', 60);`